# how to add datenow to the sql db2 date range?

Tags: sql, db2

I have the following code and I want to have date range from march 01 to datenow or current date but it was not working.

```
Select txnt_Date, item 1, item 2, item 3 
from table A
where txnt_Date between '2020-03-01' and CURRENT DATE
```

Can someone help me to fix or correct my script?

Comment: What is the problem with this code?

Comment: Please mention the error if you are getting or the data you have in your table.

Comment: Invalid operation: syntax error at or near "date"

Comment: What Db2 platform? Please edit your question with the full error message. What type is txnt_Date?

Answer (score 0):

You need to double quote mixed case names, or names with spaces in them. E.g. try

```
Select "txnt_Date", "item 1", "item 2", "item 3"
from "table A"
where "txnt_Date" between '2020-03-01' and CURRENT DATE
```